# Proof of Maclaurin series of $\ln\left(\frac{1}{2-x^2}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(1-x^2)^n}{n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I am given the Maclaurin series for $ \ln(1+x) $, namely $ \ln(1 + x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n} $ , $ -1 < x \leq  1 $.

> I now need to prove $$ \ln\left(\frac{1}{2-x^2}\right) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(1-x^2)^n}{n} \  , \  |x| < \sqrt{2}. $$

**My attempt:**

I started by rewriting the LHS:

$$ \ln\left(\frac{1}{2-x^2}\right) = - \ln(2-x^2) = -\ln\left(2\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right) = -\left(\ln2 + \ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right) $$

Then I substituted $ u = -\dfrac{x^2}{2} $ to get $ -(\ln 2 + \ln(1 + u)) $.

Next I put in the Maclaurin series for $ \ln 2 = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} $ and $ \ln(1 + u) $ (given):

$$ -(\ln 2 + \ln(1 + u)) = -\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}u^n}{n}\right) $$

I added the series together, factored out the $ (-1)^{n+1} $ and converted it to $ (-1)^n $ using the minus sign outside the series:

$$ -(\ln 2 + \ln(1 + u)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}(1 + u^n)}{n}  $$

Finally, I unsubstituted u:

$$ \ln\left(\frac{1}{2-x^2}\right) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}(1 + (-\frac{x^2}{2})^n)}{n}  $$

Some graphing shows that this series does indeed converge to the LHS, but I am stuck on how to do the algebra and convert this to the form shown in the RHS.
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20-ln(2-x%5E2)) gives the RHS but does not show its work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simpler than you think:

$$-\ln(2-x^2)=-\ln(1+1-x^2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(1-x^2)^n}{n}$$
valid whenever $|1-x^2|<1$, i.e. $|x|<\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Wow, thankyou very much! I chose completely the wrong approach. Good to see how simple it is :)